# How do i compare the values of objects in an object array?

Tags: java

My code outputs this:

```
Computer 1 bets 5
Computer 2 bets 8
Computer 3 bets 4
Computer 4 bets 3
Computer 5 bets 8
```

I want to make a method "displayWinners()" that compares the bet value of all the objects in this array and returns all of the object id's with the highest bet value, in this case it would be Computer 2 and 5 with a bet of 8. How would i do that?

```
public class Computer {
    Computer[] c;
    private int id;
    private int bet;

    public void create(int numComps) {
        int i;
        c = new Computer[numComps];

        for (i = 0; i < numComps; i++) {

            c[i] = new Computer();
            c[i].id = i+1;
            c[i].bet = bet();
            c[i].display();
        }
        displayWinners();
    }

    public int bet() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    }

    public void display() {
        String name = "Computer " + id;
        System.out.println(name + " bets " + bet);
    }

    public void displayWinners() {
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Computer c = new Computer();
        c.create(5);
    }

}
```

Comment: loop through saving the index and max value

Comment: "indexes" to be more specific

Comment: @AxelH yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you allocate a variable for an index of the maximum value and a value itself, and keep checking & rewriting the variable as function bet() is executed.

the code below is not properly verified but just have a look over.

```
public class Computer {
Computer[] c;
private int id;
private int bet;
private List<Integer> maxId;
private int maxBet;

public void create(int numComps) {
    int i;
    c = new Computer[numComps];
    maxId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    maxBet = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numComps; i++) {

        c[i] = new Computer();
        c[i].id = i+1;
        c[i].bet = bet();
        c[i].display();

        if(c[i].bet > maxBet) {
            maxId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            maxId.add(c[i].id);
            maxBet = c[i].bet;
        }
        else if(c[i].bet == maxBet) {
            maxId.add(c[i].id);
        }
    }
    displayWinners();
}

public int bet() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

public void display() {
    String name = "Computer " + id;
    System.out.println(name + " bets " + bet);
}

public void displayWinners() {
    System.out.format("Computer %d", maxId.get(0));
    if(maxId.size() > 1) {
        for(int i=1; i<maxId.size(); i++) {
            System.out.format(" and %d", maxId.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.format(" with a bet of %d\n", maxBet);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Computer c = new Computer();
    c.create(5);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just for the fun to provide this with a small trick.

You just iterate your array.
Then, I will compare the current bet with the maximum value known using [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) and base on the result, I will either:

- `r > 0`  - clear the list and add the instance to the list
- `r == 0` - Add the instance to the list
- `r < 0`  - Do nothing

Good to know, the actual value return by the method are simpler `[-1, 0, 1]`, it will matter shortly.

Now, we can see some redondance in adding into the list, to reduce that, we are able to use a `switch` instead of `if`s.

```
List<Computer> winners = new ArrayList<Computer>();
for ( Computer c : computers ){
    int r = Integer.compare(c.getBet(), maxBet);
    switch(r){
        case 1: //Current bet is higher
            maxIds.clear();
            maxBet = c.getBet();
        case 0: //Current bet is equals
            winners.add(c);
        case -1: //Current bet is lower (optional line, just for the explanation)
    }
}
```

Since I don't use `break`, after we clear the `list`, we will add into it.

Note: A fail-safe should be added in case of `Integer.compare` implementation changes. The documentation state that it will return any value instead of -1, 0 or 1. But the current implementation is simpler :

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to split storage and business logic. Move all methods for show `Computer` class out.

So to find the winners you have to do following steps:

1. Create a list of computers (you can create an array or a list);
2. Iterate over the collection once to find the highest bet;
3. Iterate over the collection second time to filter out all computers with the highest bet.

If you ask such question, then I suppose, that no need of you right now to offer different sorting algorithms or special data structures (they all do the same, but much faster for big input data).

This is one of the possible solutions (I tried to keep it simple):

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Computer[] computers = createComputer(5);
        int highestBet = getHighestBet(computers);
        List<Integer> ids = getIdsWithBet(computers, highestBet);
        System.out.println(ids.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
    }

    private static int getHighestBet(Computer... computers) {
        int max = 0;

        for (Computer computer : computers)
            max = Math.max(max, computer.getBet());

        return max;
    }

    private static List<Integer> getIdsWithBet(Computer[] computers, int bet) {
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>(computers.length);

        for (Computer computer : computers)
            if (computer.getBet() == bet)
                ids.add(computer.getId());

        return ids;
    }

    // you van use List<Computer>
    private static Computer[] createComputer(int total) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Computer[] computers = new Computer[total];

        for (int i = 0; i < computers.length; i++) {
            computers[i] = new Computer(i + 1, random.nextInt(10) + 1);
            System.out.println(computers[i]);
        }

        return computers;
    }
}

// It's better to use unmodifiable objects if you can
final class Computer {

    private final int id;
    private final int bet;

    public Computer(int id, int bet) {
        this.id = id;
        this.bet = bet;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getBet() {
        return bet;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Computer " + id + " bets " + bet;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

````
import java.util.ArrayList at top of file

```
int maxBet = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> maxIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// This is a for each loop, it is saying, for each computer in the list of computers
for ( Computer computer : computers ){
    /* if that computer has a higher bet than what we previously thought 
     was the highest, empty our list and set maxBet to that, and add this 
     computer to the list of  computers that have that bet number */
    if (computer.getBet() > maxBet){
       maxIds.clear();
       maxBet = computer.getBet();
       maxIds.add(computer.getId());
    // another computer has the same max bet value
    } else if ( computer.getBet() == maxBet){
       maxIds.add(computer.getId());
    }
}
System.out.println("Max Bet: " + maxBet);
System.out.print("Computers with max bet: ");
// for each id in our list of computers that have the max bet 
for ( int id : maxIds ){
    System.out.print(id + " ");
}
````

Comment: The only comment that would explain your code ... is incomplete.
Please explain your solution

Comment: @AxelH sorry I was still in edit mode, it is added now

Comment: The only way to `add` in that list is to `clear` it first. You will never have more than one value in your list